# Different behavior when printing Javascript Objects in console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, underscore.js

If we do a `console.log()` of an object, we see its attributes. However if the `console.log` includes other strings, we get only `[object Object]`

**Question:** Why does it not print out the object's attributes? How can we use `console.log` to print out both our string and the object's attributes? Underscore.js and node packages can be used if they help.

```
> myThing = {'name': 'Doge', 'value': 1000}
Object {name: "Doge", value: 1000}

> console.log(myThing)
Object {name: "Doge", value: 1000}

> console.log('Logging: ' + myThing)
Logging: [object Object]
```

**Desired Output**

```
Logging: Object {name: "Doge", value: 1000}
```

Answer (score 2):

--In browser

because when you use `console.log('Logging: ' + myThing)` it uses string concatenation where the object `myThing` is converted to string representation `[object Object]`

You can use

```
console.log('Logging: ', myThing)
```

or use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) - in modern browsers(for old browsers use a library like [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js))

```
console.log('Logging: ' + JSON.stringify(myThing))
```

Answer (score 2):

Node.js has a built-in module called, [`util`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html) and you can use [`util.inspect`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) to display the Object.

```
var util = require("util");
myThing = {'name': 'Doge', 'value': 1000};
console.log(myThing);
console.log('Logging: ' + myThing);
console.log('Logging: ' + util.inspect(myThing));
```

**Output**

```
{ name: 'Doge', value: 1000 }
Logging: [object Object]
Logging: { name: 'Doge', value: 1000 }
```

Comment: `console` internally uses util. And you can get any desired format by using them.

Comment: @user568109 If we `util.inspect` we can customize the depth and color parameters, right?

Comment: True, it can handle depth and colour. Comes handy for debugging.